# Fill edge-detected Text contours

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I am working on a simple OCR problem on image data.

I know this method is not ideal, and complicates a simple task, but the Canny detection is working well on so many different images that I would like to see it through:

```
gray_image = gray_image.astype('uint8')

Iedge = cv2.Canny(gray_image, 100, 200)
cnts = cv2.findContours(Iedge.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

th, im_th = cv2.threshold(Iedge, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

The input image is: [google-drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hSPlBKuEeCX1LjkJzl3pR5qAAuHQby2F/view?usp=sharing)

This gives me the following image: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpkc0.png)

I want have a binary image with only the text highlighted, by superimposing or filling the inside by findContours.
I am completely new to this, but the edge detection is giving great results on my varying sets of images.

Comment: The google drive link requires permission so we can't see the input image

Comment: Edited the link...

Comment: try add_weighted in cv2, to add the edge detected image and the original image, thus enhancing the edges even more.